# How to display the map scale in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I wonder how to display the scale map in leafleat.js. That is: I want this
[image]
instead of this
[image]
(taken to [leaflet tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/)). See the left corner of the picture.

Comment: Have a look: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-scale

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can take use of [`L.control.scale()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-scale):

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.control.scale().addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;"></div>
```